# How to get the different values based on one click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How to get the different values with same click.Please find the below code if i click on the 1st buy now button i want to get "Pendrive, 300 gms, 600". and when i click on 2nd buy now button i want to get "Mobile, 200gms, 650". in another page.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

  <div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <diV class="box">
          <div class="image">
          </div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Pendrive</h4>
            <p class="des">300 grams</p>
            <div class="price">&nbsp; &#8377; 600</div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Buy Now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <diV class="box">
          <div class="image">
          </div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Mobile</h4>
            <p class="des">200 gms</p>
            <div class="price">&nbsp; &#8377; 650</div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Buy Now</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to pass the selected value in other PHP page and apply your logic there.

Try this:-

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <diV class="box">
      <div class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Pendrive
        </h4>
        <p class="des">300 grams
        </p>
        <div class="price">&nbsp; &#8377; 600
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="sendSelectedValue('Pendrive, 300 grams, 600');">Buy Now
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <diV class="box">
      <div class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Mobile
        </h4>
        <p class="des">200 gms
        </p>
        <div class="price">&nbsp; &#8377; 650
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="sendSelectedValue('Mobile,200 gms,650 ');">Buy Now
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendSelectedValue(val){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'ajax_stack.php',
      data: {
        selected: val}
      ,
      success: function(val){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It is working fine. but how can i send ajax success data to another page. print that data in that page.